# Self-embeddings of manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

Suppose that $M$ is an oriented manifold with boundary. Consider an embedding $i: M \rightarrow M$. What is the possible topology of $M \smallsetminus i(M)$? 
More precisely, are there examples of $M$ and a collection of $i_k: M \rightarrow M$ such that $M \smallsetminus i_k(M)$ have different homology/Betti numbers?

For example, if $M^n = B^n \cup H^3$, where $H^3$ is a 3-handle, then we can write $M = ((B^n \cup H^3) \cup H^4) \cup H^3$, where $H^4$ cancels $H^3$ so that $(B^n \cup H^3) \cup H^4= B^n$. Then $H_k(M, i(M))$ is non-zero for $k = 3, 4$.

Note that if $M$ is closed and $i$ is an embedding, then $i$ must be a diffeomorphism so only the case when $M$ has boundary is interesting.

Comment: If you write $A\setminus B$ or $A\smallsetminus B$ (coded as \setminus and \smallsetminus respectively) you get the spacing appropriate to a binary operation symbol, and just as with the plus sign or the like, the spacing on the right is smaller in expressions like $+5$ or $\smallsetminus A$ than in things like $3+5$ or $B\smallsetminus A$.  With $A\backslash B$, i.e. just a backslash, that doesn't work.  I corrected it in the question. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this problem a bit more, I think 
$\dim H(M \setminus i(M)) = \dim H(\partial M)$. Indeed if $M\backslash i(M)$ is a trivial cobordism, then this is true. Maybe even $H(M \setminus i(M)) \cong H(\partial M)$ is true. However, $H(M, i(M)) \ne 0$ in general.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by $H$; is this the total homology group? In any case, the homotopy/homology type of the complement depends on $M$ and on $i$. As an exercise, consider the case when $M$ is a compact planar surface.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I think $\dim H_k( M \setminus i(M)) = dim H_k( \partial M)$ for all $k$. I checked the claim for the annulus $M  = S^1 \times I^1$, a planar surface, and I think my claim that  $\dim H_k(M \setminus i(M))$ is independent of $i$ holds. Of course, the topology of $M\backslash i(M)$ depends on $i$ but the homology does not. What counterexample do you have in mind?

Comment: Even for the closed unit disk, consider two examples: One is the identity map $i: D^2\to D^2$, the second is dilation $z\mapsto \frac{1}{2}z$. They result in different homology groups of the complement. The correct statement, I think, is about maps which send $M$ to the interior of $M$, assuming also that $M$ is compact. This should follow from Poincare duality, but I have to check.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Yes, I am assuming that $M \setminus i(M)$ is non-empty and $M$ is compact.

Comment: This is not enough even for annuli. As I said, you should assume that the image lies in the interior.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Yes, that's what I meant. The picture I had in mind is that $M \setminus i(M)$ is a non-empty cobordism between $\partial M$ and itself. I should've been more precise.